Passing variable to another component
In one component I have:
const [dirty, setDirty] = React.useState(false);
<AddItemForm addItem={addItem} setAddItem={setAddItem} dirty={dirty} />

In another component I have:
const AddItemForm = ({ setAddItem, addItem, dirty }) => {

I am trying to update dirty (when the form is changed) via:
<form id="component-form" onSubmit={onSubmit} onChange={setDirty(true)}>

So I can use this changed state in my other component - but how do you change the state as when I use setDirty it isn't available.

Either pass down the setDirty function as a prop or use a context, whatever fits your app design better

In which component is the <form> tag? Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]

This question is similar to: Is it a correct approach to pass useState setter to a child for updating parents state?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Just pass the setter function as a prop the same way you did with setAddItem.

Try this.
<form id="component-form" onSubmit={onSubmit} onChange={()=>setDirty(true)}>


Good catch but this doesn't change the fact that "setDirty it isn't available"

Correct - ReferenceError: setDirty is not defined
